# How to replace a word by another using if statement and str_replace in r

Tags: r, if-statement, str-replace

I use a dataset with string characters that contains some wrong translations. One column shows the words in the original language ("name.french"). In the next column their translations are listed ("name.english"). Now I want to use the following command to replace the wrong translations with the correct ones:

```
if(name.french == "framboise"){name.english = str_replace(name.english, "rasperry", "rasberry");}
```

However, I always get the following error message: Argument cannot be interpreted as logical value. Is there another way of replacing some wrong translations?

Comment: Please make the question [more reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try it with `ifelse`, which is vectorised and designed for this sort of thing - perhaps  `name.english <- ifelse(name.french == "framboise", "raspberry", name.english)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data are stored in two separate vectors, you can use `ifelse`:

```
name.french <- c("framboise", "not framboise")
name.english <- c("rasperry", "rasperry")


name.english2 <-
  ifelse(
    name.french == "framboise",
    str_replace(name.english, "rasperry", "rasberry"),
    name.english
  )
```

This also works if your data are stored in a `tibble` or `data.frame` and you want to use `tidyverse` verbs:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(name.french = c("framboise", "not framboise"),
            name.english = c("rasperry", "rasperry"))

d2 <- d %>%
  mutate(name.english = ifelse(
    name.french == "framboise",
    str_replace(name.english, "rasperry", "rasberry"),
    name.english
  ))

d
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name.french   name.english
#>   <chr>         <chr>       
#> 1 framboise     rasperry    
#> 2 not framboise rasperry

d2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name.french   name.english
#>   <chr>         <chr>       
#> 1 framboise     rasberry    
#> 2 not framboise rasperry
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Use `ifelse`. Assuming your data.frame is called df and you want to make changes to the name.english column:

```
df$name.english = ifelse(name.french == 'framboise', str_replace(name.english, "rasperry", "rasberry"), df$name.english)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about good old `gsub(...)` ie a `regex`based solution for your hypothetical data.frame `df`.

```
df[df[["name.french"]] == "framboise", "name.english"] <- gsub( pattern = "rasperry", replacement = "rasberry", x = df[df[[name.french == "framboise"]], "name.english"] )
```

Of cource u can easily build that into a simple function where the column name here: "name.french", the row filter criteria here: "framboise" and the pattern and replacement strings can be passed to as parameters. In case you just want to globally replace "rasperry" with "rasberry" in all of `name.english` than you can drop the row filter in the `df` ie the `df[["name.french"]] == "framboise", ...` part of the code.